# Searching for a vertical Bootstrap navbar with folding sub-items on hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a Bootstrap web site and now I'm facing a problem with the navbars.

In a nutshell, I'd like to show a vertical navigation bar with several image buttons; hovering on some of them should open an horizontal menu made up of other image buttons.
The image below sums up the idea

[image]

Do you know whether there is any Bootstrap class which can help me?

Comment: I think the best way is to create this with jQuery but maybe you can do something with the navbar example provided here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Bootstrap's navbars are not very flexible. Are you sure you definitely want the .navbar class of bootstrap ?

Comment: I only need this type of input for the user. 

I'm using Bootstrap for the GUI so I thought I had to use it (at least to keep the responsive design) but if you know any other way to accomplish this task I would be pretty happy to know.

Comment: Making stuff be triggered by hovering isn't friendly to mobile device users.

Comment: This design pattern/widget is not part of Bootstrap's CSS/js. You can add it just like any other CSS and jQuery. Hover and Mouseover, as @cvrebert, mentioned is not friendly on touch devices, so rethink your idea.

Comment: Mmm, right...Any advice?